# skip line that doesn't contain a particular character eg .colon

Tags: bash, text-processing

I am reading lines from a file in a while-loop.

```
while read line
do
  #process line
done
```

I want to skip lines that do not contain a colon.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With `bash` (also `zsh` and `ksh`), you can do like this:

```
while IFS= read -r line; do
  [[ ! $line == *:* ]] && continue
  printf '%s\n' "$line"
done
```

or using older test `[` with other `POSIX` shell:

```
[ ! -z "${line##*:*}" ] && continue
```